# Bash curl HTTP status code as variable

Tags: bash, curl

I have a curl call:

```
curl --silent --connect-timeout 8 --output /dev/null http://0.0.0.0:5000/twi?c0=24 -I -w "%{http_code}\n" ``
```

It works fine and returns 200 if succeeded. I want the status code in a variable and tried:

```
curl --silent --connect-timeout 5 --output /dev/null http://0.0.0.0:5000/twi?c0=24
```

And then:

```
curl_status=$?
echo $curl_status
```

This call works well but gives 0 as $curl_status.

I tried:

```
curl_status=$(curl --silent --connect-timeout 5 --output /dev/null http://0.0.0.0:5000/twi?c0=24)
echo $curl_status
```

With the same result: call is executed, but gives 0 as $url_status.

Why do I not get the http_code of the first call into a variable to use in an if statement?
I read many posts here with no success for a solution.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/442395/59795

Comment: Exit code ≠ HTTP status code.

Comment: Your expectation that curl uses the http status as exit code is just wrong. Read the manual if you are unsure if, it is meant for that: `man curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
curl_status=`curl --silent --connect-timeout 8 --output /dev/null http://0.0.0.0:5000/twi?c0=24 -I -w "%{http_code}\n"`
```

If you want to follow redirects use `-L`

Answer (score 1):

With help of the link from Biffen and the example from https://coderwall.com/p/taqiyg/use-http-status-codes-from-curl
I came to

```
curl_status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' --connect-timeout 3 http://0.0.0.0:5000/twi?c0=24+91+24+91+24+91+24+91)``
```

Thanks for the help.